# Weird problems with web site addressing

Tags: web, addressing

I have a number of web sites at the same address: 82.223.15.117.
The list includes [http://virtualtags.net](http://www.virtualtags.net) correctly addressed and
http://www.ipuja.net that instead leads to a weird authorization page in some dieres website, as you may check by clicking on the links.
What might be the issue?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with an old address in the dns that was apparently reassigned.